# virtual class and polymorphism

Tags: c++, class, object, polymorphism, virtual

```
class Shape
{
public:
  Shape() {size=0;}
  virtual bool isequal(const Shape& rhs){return false;};
  int size;
};
```

I have two classes (Rectangle and Cirle) which inherit from a class shape.

```
class Circle : public Shape
{
public:
  // snip
  Circle(int size): size(size) {}
  Circle(const Circle & rhs): size(rhs.size){}
  bool isequal( Shape &rhs)
  {
    Circle* rhsAsCircle = dynamic_cast<Circle*>(&rhs);
    if(rhsAsCircle == nullptr)
       return false; // not a Circle; can't be equal
    return size==rhsAsCircle->size;
  }
  int size;
};
class Rectangle : public Shape
{
public:
  Rectangle(int size1,int size2): size1(size1),size2(size2) {}
  Rectangle(const Rectangle & rhs): size1(rhs.size1),size2(rhs.size2) {}
  bool isequal( Shape &rhs)
  {
    Rectangle* rhs2 = dynamic_cast<Rectangle*>(&rhs);
    if(rhs2 == nullptr)
       return false; // not a Rectangle; can't be equal
    return (size1==rhs2->size1 && size2==rhs2->size2);
  }
  int size1;
  int size2; 
};
```

I use a class P to store different shapes in a vector and perform different operationg (ex adding rectangles/circles, deleting rectangles/circles.

```
class P
{
public:
  P(){}
  bool add(Rectangle rhs)
  {
    uint i=0;
    while (i<v.size() && rhs.isequal(*v[i])==false)
      i++;
    if (i!=v.size())
      return false;
    v.push_back(new Rectangle(rhs));
    return true;
  }
  bool add(Circle rhs)
  {
    uint i=0;
    while (i<v.size() && rhs.isequal(*v[i])==false)
      i++;
    if (i!=v.size())
      return false;
    v.push_back(new Circle(rhs));
    return true;
  }
  vector<Shape*> v;
};
```

To add a shape (rectangle or circle) I had to overload the function add. Isn't there a way to do only one function? Because circles and rectangle are shapes, no?

Comment: If you declare an abstract method `Shape* Clone() = 0;` in `Shape` then it can be called in your `add()` function (and it'll accept a generic `Shape*` instead of specialized classes). It'll push element in your vector with `v.push_back(rhs.Clone());` BTW I'd review that design if you need to make a copy of that object...probably it may be avoided.

Comment: @Adriano Thanks. Why would you review the design and what would you change?

Comment: I don't understand why you store `Shape*` but `add()` accepts `Rectangle` instead of (keeping everything else unchanged) `Rectangle*`. This forces you to create a copy of your object (`new Rectangle(rhs)`). Of course if parameter is a template object then you actually want to clone it but if it has been just created then you'll drop that object and its only purpose is to be a parameter for `add()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just pass the base class `Shape` to the `add` function. Just pass a pointer to the object to store it inside your vector `vector<Shape*> v;`

```
  bool add(Shape *shape)
  {
    uint i = 0;

    for( i = 0; i < v.size(); i++ ) {
      if(shape.isequal(*v[i]) == true)
        return false;
    }

    if ( i != v.size() )
      return false;

    v.push_back(shape);

    return true;
  }
```

Here is how this would work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Shape
{
protected:
    int m_size;
public:
    int getSize() { return m_size; }

    virtual bool isEqual(Shape *rhs) = 0;
};

class Rectangle : public Shape 
{
private:
    int m_size2;
public:
    Rectangle(int size, int size2) { m_size = size; m_size2 = size2; }

    int getSize2() { return m_size2; }

    bool isEqual(Shape *rhs)
    {
        Rectangle* rectangle = dynamic_cast<Rectangle*>(rhs);

        if(rectangle == 0)
            return false; // not a Rectangle

        return m_size == rectangle->getSize() && m_size2 == rectangle->getSize2();
    }
};

class Circle : public Shape
{
public:
    Circle(int size) { m_size = size; }

    bool isEqual(Shape *rhs)
    {
        Circle* circle = dynamic_cast<Circle*>(rhs);

        if(circle == 0)
            return false; // not a Circle

        return m_size == circle->getSize();
    }
};

class Container
{
private:
    vector<Shape*> v;
public:   
    ~Container()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
            cout << "Removind element Nr. " << i << endl;
            delete v[i];
        }
        v.erase(v.begin(), v.end());
    }

    bool add(Shape *shape) 
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {

            if( v[i] == shape ) { 
                cout << "  Element rejected (tried to add same element twice)" << endl;
                return false;
            }

            if( v[i]->isEqual(shape) ) {
                cout << "  Element rejected (an element with size " << v[i]->getSize() << " was already inside that list" << endl;
                return false;
            }

        }

        cout << "  Adding Element" << endl;
        v.push_back(shape);
        return true;
    }

    void print()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
            cout << "Size of element " << i << ": " << v[i]->getSize() << endl;
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
   Rectangle *r        = new Rectangle(1, 2);
   Circle *c           = new Circle(2);
   Circle *c_reject    = new Circle(2);
   Rectangle *r_reject = new Rectangle(1, 2);

   Container container;
   container.add(r);
   container.add(c);

   container.add(r);        // will be rejected because r was already added
   container.add(c_reject); // will be rejected 
   container.add(r_reject); // will be rejected too

   container.print();

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why would you need to cast?

Comment: haha no you're right.. I was thinking about casting a base class to child /facepalm been a long day.

Comment: @StefanR.Falk Very interesting! I need dynamic cast to check if the element is present in the vector before inserting it, right?

Comment: No. Mike was mistaken at first. You don't need to cast here. This is what polymorphism does for you. As you can see in my example code I don't need to cast anything here.

Comment: but in your example you just push_back the element in the vector. What if I want to check if the element is present in the vector? If it is present then I don't insert it, otherwise I insert it.

Comment: Well, in my code I am inserting pointers of added objects. You could just check if you receive the same address twice and you can tell if an object is already inside that list. If you want to check for equality you'd have to call you function `isEqual()` but thats something different from `isSame()`.

Comment: @StefanR.Falk I think I am going to check equality: in this case I need dynamic cast?

Comment: okay I've changed my code. it now rejects an object if it is already inside the vector and if it contains a shape that has already the same size like the element I try to add. as you can see I still don't need to cast here.

Comment: Unfortunately there is still a problem: add(new Circle(10)), then add(new Rectangle(10)). The element will be rejected. And what if I want to add more attributs (like length of the two sides for the rectangle). What do you tink?

Comment: I am sorry now I made a mistake. I updated my code. Since - like you already did correctly - each subclass has to implement its own implementation of `isEqual()`. Sorry for that mistake

Comment: Thank you, you helped me a lot. Now it seems to work very well.

Comment: May I ask you another question? :) How can I make a deep copy of the container?

Answer (score 0):

First, replace the two `add` functions with this single function:

```
bool add(const Shape& shape)
{
    uint i=0;
    while (i<v.size() && shape.isequal(*v[i])==false)
        i++;
    if (i!=v.size())
        return false;
    v.push_back(shape.clone());
    return true;
}
```

Then, implement the function `Shape* clone()` in each class that inherits class `Shape`.

Finally, declare the pure virtual function `virtual Shape* clone() = 0` in class `Shape`.